# How to pass local resource file into MediaPlayer.Create that is as dependancy?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to pass a

```
Resource.Raw.(audio file name)
```

like this

```
MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.(audio file name));
```

But this gives: Cannot convert from Int to Android.Net.Uri. I tried to convert it like this:

```
var path = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(Convert.ToString(Resource.Raw.thunder));
```

And than pass the path, but this only gives:  Cannot convert to Android.Content.Context.

Comment: `MediaPlayer` has a method `MediaPlayer.Create(Context context, int resId);` so it's strangei you get an error here,you could try this  `Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" +Resource.Raw.fileName);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was used as a dependency, instead of this:

```
MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.thunder);
```

I had to use:

```
MediaPlayer.Create(Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Raw.thunder);
```

And now it works.